# how do i send data from knowledge base of prolog to text_item element in GUI XPCE

Tags: user-interface, prolog

say for example i have these facts:

```
isacrimeorg('organization name').
isacrimeorg('Teriaka').
isacrimeorg('Piazza').
isacrimeorg('Aranelli').
```

and i have this code to pop us a window to receive data from my knowledge base

```
run:-
    new(D,dialog('Report')),    
   send(D, gap, size(20, 20)),
   send(D, append(new(SuspectedOrg, text_item('Suspected Organizations')))),
   send(D,open).
```

how do i write code to get the data from the facts(Teriaka, Piazaa, Aranelli) to be displayed in text_item element Suspected Organization in XPCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
run:-
   new(D,dialog('Report')),
   send(D, gap, size(20, 20)),
   send(D, append(new(SuspectedOrg, text_item('Suspected Organizations')))),

   findall(O, isacrimeorg(O), Os), atomic_list_concat(Os, ', ', Text),
   send(SuspectedOrg, selection, Text),

   send(D,open).
```

Comment: thanks it works, now suppose i want to read data from a text file; say for example i have 'Teriaka, Piazza, Aranelli' on one line in a text file which is called data.txt. How could i open the file and read the line and send the data to the SuspectedOrg text field. @CapelliC